# Заменить тернарник на маппинг по объекту

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть вот такой тернарник

```
     {item.file.size === 0
        ? intl.get('EMPTY_FILES_DROPZONE')
        : item.file.size > 50000
        ? intl.get('TO_LARGE_FILES_DROPZONE')
        : intl.get('INVALID_FILES_DROPZONE')}
```

Работает хорошо, но если будет больше условий будет выглядить не красиво
мне сказали заменить это на объект и по ключу выдавать текст ошибки,
я сделал что-то вроде этого

```
  const itemSizeToErrorMessage = {
    0: intl.get('EMPTY_FILES_DROPZONE'),
  };
  const tempFunc = (size: string) => {

    return itemSizeToErrorMessage[size];
  };
```

функцию tempFunc вызываю в маппинге файлов, передаю размер file.size в функцию и в зависимости от этого выдаю текст ошибки, понятно как сделать, когда размер 0, но что если размер > 50000 и тогда нужна другая ошибка, как это проверить, не делать же тернарник в функции tempFunc, так вообще не будет никакого смысла, мы обрали тернарник из jsx, но добавили его в функцию, тем еще боьлше запутали сами себя, подскажите как можно это написать именно через объект

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все равно придется либо все это делать в виде `if (...) return 'ERROR_NAME';`

либо хранить функции и выполнять их поочереди пока не выполнится условие

примерно такое:

```
const itemSizeToErrorMessage = {
    EMPTY_FILES_DROPZONE: (item) => item.file.size === 0,
    TO_LARGE_FILES_DROPZONE: (item) => item.file.size > 50000,
    INVALID_FILES_DROPZONE: (item) => true,
};

const tempFunc = (item) => {
    const key = Object.keys(itemSizeToErrorMessage)
                 .find(k => itemSizeToErrorMessage[k](item));

    return intl.get(key);
};
```

Comment: что такое string key в функции?

Comment: `string` замените на `const`, человек видимо что-то перепутал с друогого языка)

Comment: я также подумал и заменил, но в месте (item) => item.file.size приложение падает, ибо похоже не я не приложение не понимаем, как можно в объект передать item, его там просто не существует, ну я конечно понимаю что это я тупой, если что)

Comment: ладно, все я понял, работает, но блин вот кому в голову пришло так писать, почему все всегда ссылаются на чистый код и шобы понятно было, но блин это ли понятно?? Автору спасибо, это я так пар выпустил, ненавижу объекты:D

Comment: @АлексейМелентьев, ничего, скоро начнете такое понимать)